# Switching blockchain locations on a Windows machine

Tags: monerod, blockchain, windows, blockchain-data

strange thing happened.

I am in the middle of syncing blockchain ~65%, and first decided to do it on a HDD.

Apparently it needs a lot of random I/O - I can hear the disk working. It's going to take ages!(3 days according to daemon).

So I said f it and manually copied the db(entire folder) to SSD, but the daemon refused to work with that files.

Here is a command I run and results:

```
monerod.exe --db-salvage --data-dir [path]

Failed to query m_blocks: MDB_BAD_TXN: Transaction must abort, has a child, or is invalid
Error opening database: Failed to query m_blocks: MDB_BAD_TXN: Transaction must abort, has a child, or is invalid
```

I am out of ideas. Is there any special command to do it? I remember KVM had some .qcow files that had to be specially treated for them to work.

Every thread about it just says to copy the files - no you can't!

I am using TeraCopy if it is of any significance.

I will not be starting it from scratch on a SSD - out of the question.
[image: ETA]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> and manually copied the db (entire folder) to SSD, but the daemon refused to work with that

If you plan on copying / moving the database files you should ensure the daemon cleanly exits *before* copying. Otherwise you'll likely end up with a corrupt database and need to delete / resync from the start.

> Every thread about it just says to copy the files - no you can't!

Yes you can, if the daemon has cleanly exited first.

> I am using TeraCopy if it is of any significance.

I suggest you use the system's copy command or an open-source utility such as rsync. These are known to work.

> I will not be starting it from scratch on a SSD - out of the question.

Syncing to an SSD is *significantly* faster than syncing to a HDD. If your database is corrupt you likely have no choice but to start from scratch.

Comment: Thank you, using cp command in PS did the trick. 
I think I also killed the daemon previously because it was taking ages to stop(I thought it froze), and that might have also been the issue. Weirdly I didn't loose the progress.

Comment: Good to hear, glad you're on your way